# Capistrano 3 move log directory

Tags: capistrano, config, capistrano3

how can I change the directory where capistrano puts its log files? I could not find in the docs.

Currently the logs appear in `myapp/log/...` on my dev machine. However, since I am using laravel, and there is a log directory `myapp/storage/logs` I would like capistranos logs to appear here as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean the `capistrano.log` file that is created and appended to whenever you deploy?

You can specify the location by adding the following to `deploy.rb`:

```
set :format_options, log_file: "storage/logs/capistrano.log"
```

This tells Airbrussh (the default logging implementation in Capistrano 3.5.0+) where to place the log file. More information here: https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh#configuration

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.